# Rsyslog not forwarding specific log file to remote server

Tags: log, rsyslog

I am going insane trying to get rsyslog to send a specific logfile to a remote server over UDP.
This is the rsyslog.conf file for the sending server:

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#                       For more information see
#                       /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html
#
#  Default logging rules can be found in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################    

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability
$ModLoad imfile   # provides imfile module    

# provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Filter duplicated messages
$RepeatedMsgReduction on

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup adm

#
# Where to place spool files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/    
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

I then added *.* @remoteserverIP at the end of /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf.
After that I created the file /etc/rsyslog.d/test.conf with the following content:

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /var/log/test
$InputFileTag test
$InputFileStateFile stat-test
$InputFileSeverity info
InputRunFileMonitor
*.* @remoteserverIP
```

finally I created /var/log/test and did chown syslog; chgrp adm;service rsyslog restart 
My server is listening on UDP 514 

 **tcpdump udp** on sending server reveals that the logs are not being sent after doing cat "test" >> /var/log/test
logger -t test "My little pony" sends the data over UDP, is seen by tcpdump and appears on my remote server.
On sending server:

```
rsyslogd -v
rsyslogd 5.8.6, compiled with:
FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
FEATURE_LARGEFILE:                      No
GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Firewalls on either side or in between?  Usually this would talk via udp 514 .

Comment: Typo on UDP port. Has been edited =)
The sender at the moment has no iptable rules. Receiver has rule on Input chain: ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:syslog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes - a bit true. Sometimes it helps - or it is necessary - to do :

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall rsyslogd*

or instead reboot the machine totally for to reload the daemons (included rsyslogd).

You can look if syslog is scrolling ( means then that rsyslogd is working as daemon ).

Comment: Consider a HUP/reload as well -- `kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/rsyslogd.pid)`

Comment: I had today a HUP-signal too - simply then rebooted. Then anything was normal again.

Comment: Believe it ot not restalling rsyslog actually worked. Cheers!

Comment: `kill -HUP` has varying success.